# bs4 scraping data from HTML page

Tags: html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to bs4 and trying to scrape data from `table class="ids_table"`. Here is an HTML example:

```
<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="ids_table"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td"><b>First string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Second string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Third string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Fourth string</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">d</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<b>LLLM2001</b></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>12-July-2022</b></font>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">e</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<b>MLLL0056</b></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">f</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<del>AMMK0001</del><br>
 &nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>MMKA0001</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td"><font color="#00875a">&nbsp;<b>12 July 2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">i</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>ANJK1111</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">j</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>YMLC3939</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
```

I want to:

1. Scrap all `font` values from `table`.
2. Always scrap "First string"..."Fourth string" from table header (they are also in `td`, but always have the same position and values).
3. Ignore `del` in `td` (not necessary)
4. Left blank only for IDs, that are not in `font` (by IDs I mean LLLM2001, MLLL0056 etc.).

Code:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 
table = soup.find_all("table", {"class": "ids_table"})
data = [[x for x in v.find_all('td')[1:-1]] for v in table]
data = [[x.text.strip() if x.find('font') else '' for x in c] for c in data]
```

data:

```
[['',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '12-July-2022',
  '',
  '',
  '',
  '11-June-2022',
  '',
  '',
  'AMMK0001\n \xa0MMKA0001',
  '12 July 2022',
  '',
  '',
  'ANJK1111',
  '11-June-2022',
  '',
  '',
  'YMLC3939',
  '11-June-2022']]
```

As a result I want to get:

```
[['First string',
  'Second string',
  'Third string',
  'Fourth sting',
  'd'
  '',
  '12-July-2022',
  'e'
  '',
  '11-June-2022',
  'f'
  'MMKA0001',
  '12 July 2022',
  'i'
  'ANJK1111',
  '11-June-2022',
  'j'
  'YMLC3939',
  '11-June-2022']]
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please read [ask] and show us your [mre].

Comment: And don't add tags if you don't have any of these mentioned in your question. There's no `python`, `pandas`, and `bs4` used anywhere in your question.

Comment: @baduker sorry for that, I've deleted pandas part from code but forgot to remove it from tags. But what's wrong with bs4 tag? Isn't this tag related to the topic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand your 4th point, nonetheless:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

html = '''<div class="table-wrap">
<table class="ids_table"><tbody>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td"><b>First string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Second string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Third string</b></td>
<td class="ids_td"><b>Fourth string</b></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">d</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<b>LLLM2001</b></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>12-July-2022</b></font>&nbsp;</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">e</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<b>MLLL0056</b></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">f</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<del>AMMK0001</del><br>&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>MMKA0001</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td"><font color="#00875a">&nbsp;<b>12 July 2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">i</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>ANJK1111</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="ids_td">j</td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>YMLC3939</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;<font color="#00875a"><b>11-June-2022</b></font></td>
<td class="ids_td">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser") 

# remove the <del> tag
to_be_deleted = soup.select('del')[0]
to_be_deleted.decompose()
# this is how you remove the values from the 'second string' column which are not wrapped in <font> tag
tds = soup.select('b')
for x in tds[4:]:
    if x.parent.name == 'td':
        x.decompose()
# this is how you get first row - headers
table_headers = [x.text.strip() for x in soup.select_one("table.ids_table").select('tr')[0].select('td')]
# this is how you get the fonts
fonts = [x.text.strip() for x  in soup.select_one("table.ids_table").select('font')]
# this is how you display the data in an intelligible way
df = pd.read_html(str(soup))[0]
new_header = df.iloc[0]
df = df[1:]
df.columns = new_header
df
```

This returns:

```
First string    Second string   Third string    Fourth string
1   d   NaN 12-July-2022    NaN
2   e   NaN 11-June-2022    NaN
3   f   MMKA0001    12 July 2022    NaN
4   i   ANJK1111    11-June-2022    NaN
5   j   YMLC3939    11-June-2022    NaN
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed description of the code. The fourth point is about removing the values in the "First string" column that are not in the <font> tag and leaving NaN instead

Comment: I do not understand what you are saying: the values in the first column ar single letters. You mean, if that single letter is not in the font tag?

Comment: Sorry, I made a typo. Not in the "First string", but in the "Second string" column. I need to left NaN instead of value, that is in the font tag in this column.

Comment: Sorry, what you are saying makes no sense to me.

Comment: Let me put it this way, in the second column, the first two rows (LLLM2001 and MLLL0056) are missing from the <font> tag, so I need to leave NaN instead.  I hope it make sense now :)

Comment: Check my updated response: is this what you are after - only keeping the values wrapped in `<font>` tags?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I was trying to do. Thank you!